# Resolving "Undefined function 'size8cut' for input arguments of type 'uint8'" error

Tags: matlab

I have the function:

```
function Y=size8cut(X) % cut the rim of the image, to make it more fit to be cut into 256*256 patches
[m,n] = size(X);
if mod(m,8)~=0
    X=X(1:m-mod(m,8),:);
end
if mod(n,8)~=0
    X=X(:,1:n-mod(n,8));
end
    Y=X;
end
```

The error is  `Undefined function 'size8cut' for input arguments of type 'uint8'`.

Comment: Make sure `size8cut` is saved in your [current working directory](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pwd.html) or in a directory [in your MATLAB path](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html).

Comment: I just modified your question slightly to make it easier to read, and fixed a few little code formatting issues you had.

Answer (score 1):

The filename must be `size8cut.m` and the file must be on the Matlab path or your current direcory.

Comment: YES,  I am already put it inside my current directory.but still the error

Comment: If you type `which size8cut` on the Matlab command line, what do you get?